# Running mapreduce jobs on google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm running the demo that comes with the mapreduce framework. It's giving me an error:

```
 File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/webapp/_webapp25.py", line 703, in __call__
    handler.post(*groups)
  File "/path/to/mapreduce/base_handler.py", line 68, in post
    self.handle()
  File "/path/to/mapreduce/handlers.py", line 431, in handle
    self.aggregate_state(state, shard_states)
  File "/path/to/mapreduce/handlers.py", line 462, in aggregate_state
    context.COUNTER_MAPPER_CALLS))
  File "/path/to/mapreduce/model.py", line 257, in get
    return self.counters.get(counter_name, 0)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Is this something I'm doing wrong, does the demo not work? Is there more updated code somewhere else?

This is using the code from http://appengine-mapreduce.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/

Comment: At what point are you getting this error? What kind of file did you upload into the demo?

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with that code, but the latest code is the MapReduce Bundle you can download from the SDK:
https://developers.google.com/appengine/downloads

It comes with a bit of a demo.  I was able to follow this and get this to work:
http://code.google.com/p/appengine-mapreduce/wiki/GettingStartedInPython

Here's some additional notes I had when I was trying to get MapReduce running.
http://eatdev.tumblr.com/post/17983355135/using-mapreduce-with-django-nonrel-on-app-engine

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the download link. I'm able to get it running by setting up the mappers via yaml. But I'm trying to get it work via the pipeline API (like in the demo). Mainly so I'm able to run the reduce part, not just the map part.

Comment: Ah I'm probably of no help.  I thought the documentation of the Reduce portion of the pipeline was less than helpful, but luckily for me, I didn't need it.  I never got the sample running, you need to upload text files or zipped text to the blobstore yourself before it'll work, and I didn't bother with that step.